# Angular 6 RequestOptions search depreciated

Tags: angular

Migrating from Angular 4 to Angular 6. http seems to have changed a bit. Below I use to set search in my options for the request. Now it seems that is no longer the case. Can someone tell me what is should look like now?

```
getSummaryStatistics(mid: string, cp: string): Observable<SummaryStatistics> {
    const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();

    params.set('mid', mid);
    params.set('cp', cp);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    });

    let options = new Request({
        headers: headers,
        search: params //THIS IS WRONG
    });

    return this.http.get('Summary/SummaryStatistics', options)
        .map(response => <SummaryStatistics>response.json());  //ALSO .map NO LONG SEEMS TO WORK
}
```

New Attempt

Comment: The `Request` class is part of the older `Http` module. You should be using the `@angular/common/http` module, and therefore the `HttpRequest` class

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example in Angular 6 :

```
  getCadastralInformationByCoords(lat: any, lng: any, geom: boolean = true): Observable<CadastralParcel> {
    let urlToCall = urlAPIParcel;
    urlToCall += '?corx=' + lat;
    urlToCall += '&cory=' + lng;
    urlToCall += '&geom=' + geom;
    return this._http.get<CadastralParcel>(urlToCall).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        return throwError(err);
      }));
  }
```

Since Angular 5, you don't need to use `response.json()` because the method types the call by default. For more information see [Oficcial docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)